# Adding Printer Using CUPS

Tags: printer

I tried everything I know to add a printer, but I get authentication error when I use CUPS. The other way, system-setting/printers does not work either. I edited the cupsd.conf file, but no luck. I added my user ID to the lpadmin group, still no luck. It is a bit frustrating, because I had no problem adding a printer to Raspberry PI 4. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, needed a bit of research, but on the printer manufacturer's web site I found an installation program that worked.

Comment: might be a bit more helpful to users facing the same issue ... if the specific info on the printer/mfg/application was included in this post ...